# how to align javafx default alert box error icon to right side?

Tags: java, javafx

[image]

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setHeaderText("Please Enter Valid Values");
alert.showAndWait();
```

how to align javafx default alert box error icon to right side?

Comment: curious: why? If you are in a r-to-l context it should be at the right (I think, didn't check though :).

Comment: Isn't that already to the "right" side? If you want it to the left side you can simply put the header to ``null`` and add the message to the context : ``alert.setContentText("Please Enter Valid Values");``.